# Error in heroku app after database created

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm get this errors in my heroku logs. The database was created but this error is continually being logged

```
2013-01-31T18:06:06+00:00 heroku[run.9334]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2013-01-31T18:06:06+00:00 heroku[run.9334]: Awaiting client
2013-01-31T18:06:06+00:00 heroku[run.9334]: State changed from starting to up
2013-01-31T18:06:02+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by overallduka@hotmail.com
2013-01-31T18:06:10+00:00 heroku[run.9334]: Client connection closed. Sending SIGHUP to all processes
2013-01-31T18:06:11+00:00 heroku[run.9334]: Process exited with status 0
2013-01-31T18:06:11+00:00 heroku[run.9334]: State changed from up to complete
2013-01-31T18:06:16+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=youimports.herokuapp.com fwd=189.73.162.46 dyno= queue= wait= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Comment: looks like the app does not come up properly. what does ```heroku logs -t``` say when you do a ```heroku restart``` ?

Answer (score 0):

Your logs don't show any issue with postgres, although it does fail during a `rake db:migrate`.

I would verify whether `DATABASE_URL` is pointing at your database with `heroku config --app <your-app>`. If it's not, just promote your database. To do that, find out what "color" your database is via `heroku pg:info --app <your-app>`, and then promote it via `heroku pg:promote <color> --app <your-app>`.